# drupal 6 - comment form disappears when logged in

Tags: forms, drupal-6, render

I habe this code on all of my blog pages

```
drupal_get_form('comment_form', array('nid' => $nid)); ?>
```

Problem is I do not see the form when logged in as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 6 --> https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6

FYI : drupal_get_form($form_id);

In order to make it work just provide the form id to the function. Cause it only accepts one argument which should be an integer.

Next time : before posting RTFM.

It's the same thing for D7

My guess : your are making a confusion with block_load function